# C# How to identify member of a set of processes with same name?

Tags: c#, process

I have a parent app that runs multiple instances of a child app.
I want to be able to disable a 'Start'button against each of these processes should the process be running.

Getting a list of running instances of the app is easy enough (Process.GetProcessesByName("Bob")) - what I need to be able to do is loop through the list of processes returned (all of the same name) and identify which instances are running.

The instances have a public variable called ClientId - how can I read the ClientId's of the processes to see which one's are running?

Is there a better approach?

Comment: If the parent app is spawning the children then I think it needs to maintain them itself, such as by saving the PID when you launch it into a dictionary with your ClientId dentifier. Then later you can [`GetProcessById()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.getprocessbyid(v=vs.110).aspx) and the dictionary tells you which one is which. Otherwise it looks like you want [Interprocess Communication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are starting the processes with `Process.Start(fileName)`, you can store the process object returned:

```
Process myProcess = Process.Start(fileName);
```

Processes have a `HasExited` property that you can check.